# Why would Development Server be finding a specific assembly in the GAC and IIS not?

Tags: wcf, iis-7, wcf-data-services, gac

I wrote a WCF Data Service, when running it on the Development Server it runs without any issues; however, once I deploy it to IIS it throws this error `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`.
The assembly it can not find is located in the GAC. Why would Development Server be finding a specific assembly and IIS not?

Comment: WHat do you mean it runs on the development server but not IIS? What is the development server then?

Comment: The ASP.NET Development Server. It's the server that Visual Studio runs the solution in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enabling 32 bit applications on the Application Pool fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just my guess, but I reckon the assembly is compiled as .net 4 and IIS is running under .net 3.5. Check [here](http://frejnorling.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/configure-iis-7-5-to-manage-asp-net-4-0-web-pages/).

Comment: My Target Framework is .NET Framework 4 and my Application Pool is set to ASP.NET v4.0.

Comment: Have you also disabled any ISAPI restriction?

Comment: I just removed all restrictions, but it is still throwing the File Not Found Exception.

Comment: Try reinstalling asp.net using aspnet_iisreg.exe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(VS.100).aspx

Comment: I went and deployed the project on an other machine and received the same error. So I don't think there is an issue with aspnet_iisreg.exe.